# C# code for Dhond't voting method UK Parliament

Tags: c#, object-oriented, classes

Please can you check if the code I have written follows 4 rules of OOP well enough, if there is anything that could be improved or is just wrong I am happy to change (very new to C# sorry if it's awful).

The code implements the "Dhond't Method" which is a polling system. https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-27187434

MAIN

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Voting_System
{
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Establish the file path 
            string filepath = @"C:\Users\mathe\OneDrive\Documents\All Assignments\Voting System\input\data.txt";

            // Store values in a list of string
            List<string> file = File.ReadAllLines(filepath).ToList();

            // Puts each party into a list of Party and display Name + Votes
            List<Party> partys = new List<Party>();
            foreach (string line in file)
            {
                string[] items = line.Split(',');
                Party p = new Party(items[0], Convert.ToInt32(items[1]));
                partys.Add(p);
            }

            // Ask user for thresh hold and also calculate total votes
            Console.WriteLine("What is the threshold for partys (%) (round number) ?");
            int thresHold = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Ask user how many seats they want to allocate
            Console.WriteLine("\nHow many seats do you want to allocate in total? (round number)");
            int seatsCount = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Calcutions for Dhon't method
            int totalVotes = SumOfVotes(partys);
            DisplayPercentageVotes(partys, thresHold, totalVotes);
            CalculateDhondt(partys, seatsCount);
            DisplayWinningParties(partys);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // Print out all partys and there properties to user
        private static void DisplayWinningParties(List<Party> partys)
        {
            foreach (Party p in partys)
            {   
                if (p.Seats > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p);
                }
            }
        }

        // Find total votes
        private static int SumOfVotes(List<Party> partys)
        {
            int totalVotes = 0;
            foreach (Party p in partys)
            {
                totalVotes += p.Votes;
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"\nTOTAL No OF COMBINED VOTES FOR ALL PARTIES 2020 : {totalVotes}\n");
            return totalVotes;
        }

        // Displays percent of votes for each party 
        private static void DisplayPercentageVotes(List<Party> partys, int threshold, int totalvotes)
        {
            // Displays percent of votes for each party 
            Console.WriteLine($"PARTIES THAT MEET THE {threshold}% INPUTTED THRESHOLD:");
            foreach (Party p in partys)
            {
                if (p.PercentOfVotes(totalvotes) > threshold)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} has {Math.Round(p.PercentOfVotes(totalvotes),2)} % of total votes.");
                }
            }
        }

        // Method to do the main caclutions of the Dhon't method
        private static void CalculateDhondt(List<Party> partys, int seatsCount)
        {
            // Find intial party with highest votes
            Party biggestVote = partys.Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1.Votes > v2.Votes ? v1 : v2);
            biggestVote.Seats += 1;
            biggestVote.DivideParty();

            // Keep looping through partys and applying dhond't method until all seats are taken
            int totalSeatsCount = 0;
            while (totalSeatsCount != seatsCount)
            {
                Party biggestVotes = partys.Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1.NewVotes > v2.NewVotes ? v1 : v2);
                biggestVotes.Seats += 1;
                biggestVotes.DivideParty();

                foreach (Party p in partys)
                {
                    totalSeatsCount += p.Seats;
                }
                // If we havent reached desired seats count reset the total seats variable
                if (totalSeatsCount != seatsCount)
                {
                    totalSeatsCount = 0;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"\nWE HAVE {seatsCount} SEATS ALLOCATED:");
        }
    }
}
```

PARTY CLASS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Voting_System
{
    class Party
    {
        // properties for each party
        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public int Votes { get; private set; }
        public int NewVotes { get; set; }
        public int Seats { get; set; }

        // Constructor for party class 
        public Party(string name, int votes)
        {
            Name = name;
            Votes = votes;
            NewVotes = votes;
        }

        // Returns percentage of votes for your party
        public double PercentOfVotes(double totalVotes) => (Votes / totalVotes) * 100;

        // When ever you print the object of this class return this
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Name: {Name} Votes: {Votes} Seats: {Seats}";
        }

        // Applies Dhond't method of division 
        public void DivideParty()
        {
            NewVotes = Votes / (1 + Seats);
        }
    }
}
```

DATA INPUT FILE

```
Brexit Party,452321,BP1,BP2,BP3,BP4,BP5;
Liberal Democrats,203989,LD1,LD2,LD3,LD4,LD5;
Labour,164682,LAB1,LAB2,LAB3,LAB4,LAB5;
Conservative,126138,CON1,CON2,CON3,CON4,CON5;
Green,124630,GR1,GR2,GR3,GR4,GR5;
UKIP,58198,UKP1,UKP2,UKP3,UKP4,UKP5;
Change UK,41117,CUK1,CUK2,CUK3,CUK4,CUK5;
Independent Network,7641,INET1,INET2,INET3,INET4,INET5;
Independent,4511,IND1;
```

Comment: What do mean by this: *4 rules of encapsulation* ? Did you mean the four principles / pillars of Object Oriented Programming?

Comment: @PeterCsala yes do you think ive included the pillars well enough? if not any improvement tips? thanks alot

Comment: Are you sure that you have applied any of the principles? This lengthy `Main` function does not indicate that.

Comment: Please read [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/intro-to-csharp/object-oriented-programming)

Comment: @PeterCsala I have updated the main would this be better?

Comment: Can you add the Party class please

Comment: @AlanT Yeh sorry i added it

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks for the explaination,so for me should i make a static method to sort out the file path, and another static method to put each party into a list of parties?

Comment: From your algorithm implementation perspective are these relevant? Probably not. From the algorithm point of view what matter is to receive the already parsed data. It does not matter that it comes from a json file or a database or via UDP messages. These are implementation details, so they should be handled inside the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

In this review I'll focus only on **Abstraction** and **Encapsulation** because the other two is not applicable in this scenario.

---

Whenever we are talking about OOP then we usually refer to well-defined objects (with known responsibilities) which are communicating with each other to solve a greater problem.

#### Abstraction

We are decomposing the original problem into many smaller chunks. These can be solved either independently or via collaboration. If you implement a specific algorithm then usually there is a coordinator / orchestrator which conducts the communication between the objects.

This coordinator role (logic) can reside inside your `Main` method:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var parameters = DhondtMethodAlgorithmParameters.GatherFromConsole();
    var inputData = DhondtMethodAlgorithmInput.LoadFromFile(inputFilePath);
    
    var algorithm = new DhondtMethodAlgorithm(parameters, inputData);
    var results = algorithm.PerformCalculation();
    
    DisplayResults(results);
}
```

- Here we have 3 different stages:

  - Gathering data and converting them to the desired shape
  - Setting up the algorithm and calling it
  - Showing the calculation's result

We have divided the original problem into smaller chunks where each does have a well-defined scope and responsibility. We have to continue this split until we reach a point from which we can't further divide.

This exercise will help us to identify the objects and their exposed behavior.

#### Encapsulation

In order to properly use encapsulation we have to hide our implementation details behind the abstraction. In other words the abstraction should guarantee that the data is consistent all the time from the consumer point of view.

For example, we are not creating an `DhondtMethodAlgorithmParameters` instance if the user provided data is malformed. We can early exit with an exception or we can retry to gather again the parameters from the user. Whenever we have passed the `GatherFromConsole` factory method then we can be sure that the returned `DhondtMethodAlgorithmParameters` contains only valid data.

Same applies for `LoadFromFile`. There can be a lot of different problem (like the file does not exist, the data is corrupted, etc.) that the code may or may not tackle. But from the Abstraction and Encapsulation point of view whenever the function returns with the parsed and validated input data (`DhondtMethodAlgorithmInput` instance) then we can be sure that it is in a consistent state.

From an algorithm point of view the encapsulation can mean that its input and parameters are immutable after creation. It does not expose any method or member with which the consumer of the algorithm instance can change the underlying data.

---

So, in short:

1. Identify objects and their responsibilities << Abstractions
2. Expose only those members that are needed for collaboration << Encapsulation