# Making a Dhond't system in C# by reading from a data file

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I wanted to know if i have used abstraction and encapsulation effectively here, and if not where can i improve thank you. (follow up from my unworking previous version)

MAIN

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace Voting_System
{
    class Program
    {  
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Puts each party into a list of Party and display Name + Votes
            Console.WriteLine("Type the name of the file your data is in with the .txt extension : ");
            string data = Console.ReadLine();

            // Make list of party classes to hold all parties from data.txt file
            List<Party> partys = FindData(data);

            // Ask user for thresh hold and also calculate total votes
            Console.WriteLine("What is the threshold for partys (%) (round number) ?");
            int threshHold = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            // Calcutions for Dhon't method
            var votesAndSeats = GetSumVotesAndSeats(data);
            DisplayPercentageVotes(partys, threshHold, votesAndSeats.Item1);
            CalculateDhondt(partys, votesAndSeats.Item2);
            DisplayWinningParties(partys);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        // takes input of the name of the data file and outputs the required data
        private static List<Party> FindData(string exactpath)
        {
            // Store values in a list of string
            List<string> file = File.ReadAllLines(exactpath).ToList();
            List<Party> partys = new List<Party>();
            foreach (string line in file.Skip(3))
            {
                string[] items = line.Split(',');
                Party p = new Party(items[0], Convert.ToInt32(items[1]), items.Skip(2).ToArray());
                partys.Add(p);
            }
            return partys;
        }

        // Print out all partys that have seats and there properties to console
        private static void DisplayWinningParties(List<Party> partys)
        {
            foreach (Party p in partys)
            {   
                if (p.SeatsAmount > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p);
                }
            }
        }

        // Find total votes for all parties and number of seats to be allocated
        private static (int,int) GetSumVotesAndSeats(string exactpath)
        {
            List<string> file = File.ReadAllLines(exactpath).ToList();
            int totalElectionVotes = Convert.ToInt32(file[2]);
            int numOfSeatAllocation = Convert.ToInt32(file[1]);

            return (totalElectionVotes, numOfSeatAllocation);
        }

        // Displays percent of votes for each party that meets the threshold
        private static void DisplayPercentageVotes(List<Party> partys, int threshold, int totalvotes)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine($"Parties that meet the {threshold}% threshold :");
            foreach (Party p in partys.ToList())
            {
                if (p.PercentOfVotes(totalvotes) > threshold)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p.Name} has {Math.Round(p.PercentOfVotes(totalvotes), 2)}" +
                                      $" % of total votes.");
                }
                else
                {
                    partys.Remove(p);
                }
            }
        }

        // Method to do the main calculations of the Dhon't method
        private static void CalculateDhondt(List<Party> partys, int seatsCount)
        {
            // Find intial party with highest votes
            Party biggestVote = partys.Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1.Votes > v2.Votes ? v1 : v2);
            biggestVote.SeatsAmount += 1;
            biggestVote.DivideParty();

            // Keep looping through partys and applying dhond't method until all seats are taken
            int totalSeatsCount = 0;
            while (totalSeatsCount != seatsCount)
            {
                // If we havent reached desired seats count reset the total seats variable
                totalSeatsCount = 0;

                Party biggestVotes = partys.Aggregate((v1, v2) => v1.NewVotes > v2.NewVotes ? v1 : v2);
                Console.WriteLine(biggestVotes);
                biggestVotes.SeatsAmount += 1;
                biggestVotes.DivideParty();

                foreach (Party p in partys)
                {
                    totalSeatsCount += p.SeatsAmount;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"\n{seatsCount} seats allocated :");
        }
    }
}
```

PARTY CLASS

````
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Voting_System
{
    class Party
    {
        // Fields
        private string _name = "unknown";
        private int _votes;
        private string[] _seatsCodeValues;
        private int _newVotes;
        private int _seatsAmount;

        // Properties 
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            private set { _name = value; }
        }

        public int Votes
        {
            get { return _votes; }
            private set { _votes = value; }
        }

        public string[] SeatsCodeValues
        {
            get { return _seatsCodeValues; }
            private set { _seatsCodeValues = value; }
        }

        public int NewVotes
        {
            get { return _newVotes; }
            private set { _newVotes = value; }
        }

        public int SeatsAmount
        {
            get { return _seatsAmount; }
            set { _seatsAmount = value; }
        }

        // Constructor for party class 
        public Party(string name, int votes, string[] seatsCodeValues)
        {
            Name = name;
            Votes = votes;
            NewVotes = votes;
            SeatsCodeValues = seatsCodeValues;
        }


        // Returns percentage of votes for your party
        public double PercentOfVotes(double totalVotes) => (Votes / totalVotes) * 100;

        // When ever you print the object of this class return this
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"Name: {Name}, Votes: {Votes}, {SeatsAmount} " +
                   $"Seats Values : {string.Join(",", SeatsCodeValues.Take(SeatsAmount))}";
        }

        // Applies Dhond't method of division 
        public void DivideParty()
        {
            NewVotes = Votes / (1 + SeatsAmount);
        }
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Please mention in your post that this question is a follow-up of [your previous one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/256309/c-code-for-dhondt-voting-method-uk-parliament)

Comment: @PeterCsala i have now.

Answer (score 2):

Quick remarks:

- Whenever I create a `Console` app, the first thing I do is add a `Runner` class with a `public void Execute()` method, and then call that from the `Main()` of the `Program` class. And then the whole logic is in that `Runner` class.
- Your `Program` class is 100+ lines long, and contains various methods. Each of them does something fairly specific, but I'd actually move some of them to their own class (e;g. the ones that read the file data).
- Follow the Microsoft guidelines WRT naming. For instance `exactpath` is a compound word, and thus should be `exactPath`. You also should not use non-alphanumeric characters, e.g. the underscore in `Voting_System`.
- Use descriptive names. `exactPath` strikes me as odd: is there an `inexactPath`? `data` in `string data = Console.ReadLine();` is wrong on so many levels: it is too generic a name and doesn't describe what it is. `FindData` is too generic a method name.
- `Console.WriteLine("Type the name of the file your data is in with the .txt extension : ");` seems to require the user to type a file ***name***, but it is clear you expect a ***path***. That is a major difference.
- Comments should be sparse and should tell me why, not what. For instance `// Store values in a list of string` doesn't tell me anything your code hasn't already told me. Same for `// Constructor for party class` and most other comments.
- Use proper English. `partys` is wrong, it's `parties`.
- Do not needlessly abbreviate. While the "p" in `foreach (Party p in partys)` isn't that bad and the context gives me enough information, it still would be better to just use the word `party`.
- `DisplayPercentageVotes` does more than what its name says: it also alters the contents of  `partys`. Thus it should be two methods.
- Why does `Party` have these "old style" getter/setters?
- Many of your `foreach` loops could be replaced with LINQ calls.
- You don't check the user input. You don't check whether the user-provided file path exists, you don't check whether the contents of the file are structured properly,...

Comment: I appreciate the help but alot of the stuff likemlinq and error handling wasnt expected by us,as this is our first project in our c# module

Comment: What do you mean by make a class for just the read file data? and when you say old style getters and setters should i do something like public string Name { get; private set; } instead? would this still meet encapsulation and abstraction pillars?

Comment: An alternative way of doing encapsulation is https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/encapsulation-csharp/ , but honestly, I haven't seen such code in "real life" in ages. If your teacher requires you to write it that way (with private fields etc.), you'll need to do it, but it isn't a coding style you see often these days (except for WPF and Unity etc.).

Comment: Ok thanks,also can you explain why i would need to make a class for the file handling code segments?

Comment: It's what I would do, for a simple reason: I don't like long class files where I need to scroll from method to method. Sometimes that is inevitable, but as much as possible I try to move specific logic to its own class file. Reading a file and converting its contents to a list of custom objects is something I'd move to its own class, for instance.